# Convergence of an increasing function under a constraint

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I would like to prove the following claim:

Claim: Suppose that $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function. If there exists some $N>1$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(f(x)-f(x/N))=0$, then the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$ exists, i.e., is finite.

Considering the contrapositive with unbounded increasing functions such as $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=e^{x}$ makes the claim seem plausible but I am not sure if it is true. Counterexample(s) would be great if you can think of any.

Comment: You need a function that grows slowly. Very slowly. Slower than $\log$.

Comment: It sure looks like it is true.  Let me think if I can develop a proof.

Comment: @DougM It's not true, your time is better spent looking for a counterexample.

Comment: That is indeed what I did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose:

$f(x) = \ln(\ln(x))\\
f(x/N) = \ln(\ln(x/N)) = \ln(\ln(x)-\ln(n))\\
f(x) - f(x/N) = \ln\frac{\ln x}{\ln(x)-\ln(n)}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\ln\frac{\ln x}{\ln(x)-\ln(n)} = 0
$

Comment: Great, thanks! A fast drop in the rate of increase seems like the main point.